# DataTables - Get data that's in the JSON but not in the table/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

So I'm using DataTables to pull data from a local JSON file into a table. I'm trying to apply hyperlinks to every cell in a particular column but the URL itself is made up of data that is stored in the JSON, but I don't display it in the table because the user doesn't need to see it.

Simplified example:

Table:

```
|  Name   |
-----------
| Apple   |
| Pear    |
| Orange  |
```

Generated from:

```
{Fruits:[
    {
    "Name":"Apple",
    "id"  :"123"
    },
    {
    "Name":"Pear",
    "id"  :"456"
    },
    {
    "Name":"Orange",
    "id"  :"789"
    }
]}
```

So Pear would have a link to something like `http://example.com/?pageid=456` without "id" ever being displayed anywhere in the table.

Something like `<a href="http://example.com/?pageid={{id}}">{{name}}</a>` would be how I'd do it in handlebars but alas, I'm using DataTables.

I thought about putting the ID for the URL in the table and then just hiding it so I can just grab it out the DOM using jQuery but that feels hacky to me.

Comment: Check out `fnRowCallback` in the dataTable options: http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fnRowCallback` in the options when you initialize the `dataTable`:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    var a = $('<a />').attr({
            "class": "some-class",
            "id": "fruit" + aData.id,
            "href": "http://example.com/?pageid=" + aData.id
        }).text(aData.Name);
    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).empty().append(a); //assumes you want this in the first column
}
```